# Offline Map (with mark by coordinates) on asp.net

Tags: asp.net, angular, maps

I need a recommendation for static map  (I mean that I don't need to identify my location),

which can be marked many places at the same time (the marked will be by coordinates).

I am developing in VS 2017. (client: angular2)

it's for a internal website/application (the computer not connected to the internet, for safe reason). the kind is: world / my land

Do you have a recommendation?

Thank you

Comment: I think it is pretty unclear, maybe you should put more details on the need, e.g. why map should be "offline" on an online web site, what kind of map it is, world/region/area, etc.

Comment: it's for a internal website/application (the computer not connected to the internet, for safe reason). the kind is: world / my land.